# Запуск стороннего приложения из своей Unity3d игры на Андроид

Tags: android, unity3d, мобильные-приложения

Можно ли сделать такой функционал в Unity3d на мобильном устройстве: нужно чтобы при клике по кнопке на сцене запускать стороние приложения которые установленые на Android устройстве. Например запускать приложение:(Twitter или Facebook), и делать проверку если такого приложения нету на устройстве, то переходить в маркет на скачку этих приложений.